# How can I have 1 image stretch across multiple workspaces?

Tags: compiz, appearance, desktop-background

Basically, I have a quad-monitor wallpaper that I want to stretch across all of my workspaces (1 monitor), I have compiz manager installed, but can't seem to get the single image to fill the entire cube. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be accomplished by splitting the image into four different images and adding a different one on each desktop.

You could use a variety of different things to split the images. Using ImageMagick:

1. Open a terminal
2. If ImageMagick isn't installed yet, install it: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`
3. Split it! `convert imagename.png -crop 25%x100% imagename-%02d.png`

25% was used above based on a setup of four desktops. If you have a different number use 100/#ofDesktops

Now, setup the compiz plugin to use them:

1. System --> Preferences --> CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Enable "Desktop Cube"
3. Select "Desktop Cube" and go to the "Appearance" tab
4. "Add" the images you created above under "Background Images"
5. Make sure they are ordered correctly

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happens. I disabled showDesktop in nautilus, but I just get all black transparent wallpapers.

Comment: @BBetances Are the images themselves outputted blank when they are split? or are they just not being displayed correctly?

Comment: They split up fine, but the wallpaper doesn't render. I gave up for now due to other things, but I'll give it another shot this week.

Comment: You need to use the wallpaper plugin instead of the cube's wallpaper option. I don't know why cube ever gained this feature and it has since been removed in compiz 0.9.x releases.